# Quartz in cluster environment with out jobstore

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to run quartz scheduler without conflict in clustered env without jdbc job store . I am not thinking of maintaining the state either in user defined tables

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Clustering Quartz Scheduler with Terracotta](http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/quartz-scheduler/installation-guide)

You can find an example in [Quartz distribution](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/downloads/) (Look for Example 15 - TC Clustered Quartz)